# Objective-C: Divide two integers and return a rounded integer value

Tags: objective-c, ios, int

How can I divide two NSIntegers, for instance, 13 / 4 and round the result to the next integer = 3?

I have seen some samples converting the integers to float and back to integer. 
But what is the recommended way with the least amount of code to do it?

Comment: What rounding do you want to occur when the quotient is exactly halfway between two integers, including the various combinations of positive and negative numerator and denominator? Should it round to even, toward zero, or something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming `x >= 0` and `y > 0`:

If you want to round down: `x / y`

If you want to round up: `(x + y - 1) / y`

If you want to round to nearest: `(x + y / 2) / y`